# Timer Skipping ElapsedEvents

Tags: c#, timer

So I'm trying to run an event every 5 seconds. Seems to work using System.Timers.Timer to some extend but it seems to be skipping sometimes, not even responding late, just plain skipping it.

Anything I could do about this?

```
        internal void DetermineScreenCapping()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer ScreenCapTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            /// Initialize the screencapper (doesn't enable it yet)
            // Tell the timer what top do when it elapses
            ScreenCapTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ExecuteCode);
            // Set it to go off every five seconds
            ScreenCapTimer.Interval = 5000;
            // And start it        
            ScreenCapTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    private void ExecuteCode(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsCurrentlyWorking == true)
        {
            Execute Code
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's with the -1? Is this really such a dumb question?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves down vote

Comment: How do you know that the event is skipped? Can you verify it by adding a log entry with timestamp the first thing in "ExecuteCode"?

Comment: Well, the code exports files with timestamps for the names, that's how I know. a lot of the time it's 5 seconds difference, however sometimes it's 10, 15 or i've even seen up to 30 seconds for some reason

Comment: @user1071461: I think you need to do some more detailed debugging. Put a `Debug.WriteLine()` style debug call in your callback to verify that it is actually skipping callbacks (which I can't imagine it would be).

Comment: @user1071461 I would recommend to write log entries when entering and leaving the method `ExecuteCode` so you can see that it's not your processing code that delays the writing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indeed wasn't the timer not doing it's job. It was the code being executed that had some problems that couldn't even be seen debugging for some reason.

I changed the code and the timer works properly now ^^